# System Activity Report (sar) - how can I preserve color, but disable extra header lines? (and use less)

Tags: system, monitoring

If you run `sar` without parameters, the output is in color, but with extra headers inserted after each page. If you run `sar | cat` the extra headers are removed, but so is the coloring.

If you would like to pipe into less, running `sar | less` have the same effect as using `cat`  - extra headers are removed, but so are colors. If you would like to preserve color with `less`, you can use `unbuffer` (which is installed as a part of `expect`) and `less -R`, but then the extra headers appear again.

I believe this is better shown in pictures below (the extra headers are marked in image 2).

The result of `sar | less`:
[image]

The result of `unbuffer sar | less -R`:
[image]

So is it at all possible to preserve colors with the `sar` command using `less`, and at the same time **not** have the extra header lines for each page (as marked in image 2)?

I reckon it might be possible to do this with some elaborate `awk`/`grep`/`sed` piping (and maybe chained commands), but I would prefer a more straight solution with the commands themselves, if this is at all possible. This is also due to the fact that I would like to pipe the result to `less` using a single command.

I'm using Ubuntu Server 22.04.

Comment: Does `S_COLORS=always sar | less` do the trick? I don't have a working `sar` to test with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have never used `sar`, but `man sar` mentions that `sar` has an environment variable whose value controls this behavior:

> S_COLORS
>
> By default statistics are displayed in color when the output is connected to a terminal.  Use this
> variable to change the settings. Possible values for this variable are never, always or auto  (the
> latter is equivalent to the default settings).

There are various tools that change their output depending on whether they are being piped to something or just printing toa terminal and many have an `always` option to ensure color is used regardless. For instance, see the `--color` options of `grep` and `ls`. It looks like `sar` is using an environment variable for the same thing, so just try this:

```
S_COLORS=always sar | less -R
```

The `-R` option for `less` allows the preservation of colors and hyperlinks in the text being piped.

Comment: Thanks. I must admit that I had overlooked that entry in the man page. I guess I was focused on command options, and not an environment variable. 